# Is MySQL VSS "Safe" Yet?

Tags: windows, mysql, vss

From what I'm reading, there's plenty of statements that MySQL is at least partially VSS (Volume Snapshot Service) aware, with caveats etc. but all of the things I can find online regarding this are at least 2 years old.

I was hoping for someone to give me an indication about the current state of MySQL with VSS? Is it completely supported? If not, will it ever be? If not, well, what are our alternatives? We're trying to do intermittent backups of a production database but with GBs of data a simple mysqldump is not cutting it.

Thanks for any tips, tricks, notes or advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the only bug I could find, and it's a pending feature request without recent updates:

[Bug #35668 - add support for microsoft volume shadow copy services as windows backup method](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35668)

R1Soft's [CDP w/ MySQL plugin](http://www.r1soft.com/windows-cdp/cdp-enterprise-edition/mysql/) is a solution that allows online backups (albeit not cheap.)

Comment: Thanks Dave: I found the same bug and was slightly saddened by the lack of any updates...